# Avoid new page in new section

Tags: sectioning, article

I'm using article, and I have a few section. the problem is that I don't know how avoid new page when there is a new section

Comment: please don't use external links, your question is archived here forever and will not be understandable if you change that project. But use `\input` not `\include` `\include` always starts a new page.

Comment: Thank you it works!

Comment: I fix the question for future readers, you're right

Comment: for your next question but this one is a very common duplicate so it doesn't really matter:-)